# TAFC to TAFJ routine conversion in T24 - T(EB.ATM19.FROM.DATE)<3> = 'NOINPUT'

Tags: temenos

Currently I am retrofitting `TAFC` routine to `TAFJ` routines. While converting I have found something like T Function in `TAFC`. In `TAFJ` I have converted this like this way,
EB.SystemTables.setT(EB.ATM19.ATTRIBUTE4, 'NOINPUT')
But I am wondering why <3> is used in the T Function of `TAFC`?
If anyone can explain it would be a great help.